# How can I pass state to Tab render method in semantic ui react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using Tab from [SUIR](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab/#usage-active-index)
I'm trying to pass some state data into one of the "panes" and use the `<Dropdown>` module to render that state data. Do I need to pass down via props, or something else?

I want to render a dropdown that's specific to `Tab 2`. I'm really just wondering how to pass state data to the render method of the panes. I was thinking maybe move the render method out of `panes = [{},{},{}]` and put it in `render()` of the `App`. I'm not sure the best approach here.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/40jomz9nm0) of below code.

```
const panes = [
  { menuItem: "Tab 1", render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: "Tab 2", render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 2 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: "Tab 3", render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 3 Content</Tab.Pane> }
];

const MockAdapter = require("axios-mock-adapter");
const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

mock.onGet("/dataschemas").reply(200, {
  data: [
    {
      id: "2",
      selfUri: "/dataschemas/2",
      type: "DataSchema",
      name: "Book Catalog"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      selfUri: "/dataschemas/3",
      type: "DataSchema",
      name: "Business Articles"
    }
  ]
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { activeIndex: 1, dataschemas: [], dataSchemaName: "" };
  }

  handleRangeChange = e => this.setState({ activeIndex: e.target.value });
  handleTabChange = (e, { activeIndex }) => this.setState({ activeIndex });

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getSchemas();
  }

  getSchemas = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/dataschemas");
      console.log(data);
      const dataschemas = data.data;

      this.setState({ dataschemas: dataschemas });

      console.log("This is the dataschema list:", dataschemas);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(Error(`Error fetching results list: ${error.message}`));
    }
  };

  handleSchemaChange = e => {
    //handle data schema dropdown change
  };

  // Example of dropdown using dataschemas state

  render() {
    const { activeIndex, dataschemas, dataSchemaName } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>activeIndex: {activeIndex}</div>
        <input
          type="range"
          max="2"
          value={activeIndex}
          onChange={this.handleRangeChange}
        />
        <Tab
          panes={panes}
          activeIndex={activeIndex}
          onTabChange={this.handleTabChange}
        />
        <Dropdown
          placeholder="Select data schema"
          scrolling
          clearable
          fluid
          selection
          search
          noResultsMessage="Try a different Search"
          multiple={false}
          options={dataschemas.map(schema => {
            return {
              key: schema.id,
              text: schema.name,
              value: schema.name
            };
          })}
          header="PLEASE SELECT A DATASCHEMA"
          value={dataSchemaName}
          onChange={this.handleSchemaChange}
          required
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, I can think of the following solutions:

1. Looking at your layout I think there's no need to pass the state to panes render methods since you have `Dropdown` component outside of it. So you can just define the options of `Dropdown` based on `activeIndex` value.
2. If you want to move `Dropdown` component inside tab content (well, which makes sense) then you can

   - Create separate components for each tab content (`TabContent1`, `TabContent2`, etc - can figure out more suitable names of course) and then create `panes` inside of `render()` as you suggested:

     ```
     const panes = [
       { menuItem: "Tab 1", render: () => <TabContent1 {/* can pass props here */} /> },
       { menuItem: "Tab 2", render: () => <TabContent2 /> },
       { menuItem: "Tab 3", render: () => <TabContent3 /> }
     ]
     ```

     And you can additionally pass some props to those components there if you want to.
     Now, if the content of the tabs content is very similar you can create one 
     generic `TabContent` component and just pass there props will be different like `dropdownOptions={...}`
   - Same as prev example, but instead of creating new component (if you think it's too much fuss) just create a separate `renderTabContent()` method and also create `panes` in `render()` like this:

     ```
     const panes = [
       { menuItem: "Tab 1", render: () => this.renderTabContent(
         /* can pass something here as well */
       )},
       { menuItem: "Tab 2", render: () => this.renderTabContent() },
       { menuItem: "Tab 3", render: () => this.renderTabContent() }
     ]
     ```

     Again, you can pass something to this method like `dropdownOptions` to make each of them return different content. Or you can create different `renderTabContent1`, `renderTabContent2` etc for each tab content. Inside of these methods you can easily access `this.state`

This is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xl3702568w) example with a #2 solution. I created just one `Tab2Content` component but I believe you'll be able to pick up the idea and implement other components

Comment: Each tab will be rendering something entirely different so I think 3 separate component would be the best approach actually. Could you maybe provide a brief edit to the sandbox displaying one of your solutions, so I can mark this as correct?

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Maybe this is a quick fix, but what if I need several dropdown selection in the same tab, do I add another `<Dropdown>`module inside the `Tab2Content` component? Or add another object to `dropdownOptions` in render of main?https://codesandbox.io/s/6nvp9j20nr

Comment: I added `dropdownOptions` in my codesandbox just as an example in case if several of your TabContents have similar content (sorry, it apparently wasn't clear). So that there's no need to create 3 different TabContent components, but just one that you provide different dropdown options to. But if you're going to have different content under each tab then you create separate TabContent components for each Tab without `dropdownOptions` props since such prop makes little sense in this case. So you can define multiple `Dropdown` components there and store options/values inside `Tab2Content`

Comment: I tried adding an additional dropdown in the same tab, but can't quite get it to work. It's only rendering the second dropdown I added

Comment: I think I solved it now, `<Tab2Content dropdownOptions1={{ ... }} dropdownOptions2{{ ... }} />`. Not sure if this is the best way, but it's working